# Matlab: Read from serial line by line

Tags: matlab

I have the micro-controller sending data over serial successfully to a terminal with carriage returns to indicate when a new set of data starts. I configure my serial port connection as such:

```
s_connection = serial('/path/to/device', 'BaudRate', 9600);
s_connection.BytesAvailableFcnMode = 'terminator';
s_connection.BytesAvailableFcn = @updatePlot;
s_connection.Terminator = 'CR';
```

This code successfully calls my `BytesAvailableFcn` exactly once, and then never again. In my `BytesAvailableFcn` I have tried using `fscanf` and `fgetl` to get the text being sent, both of which work. However, the issue is that I cannot seem to get the next line the device sends (terminated by a carriage return) to be received by my Matlab code, or at least it is not triggering my `BytesAvailableFcn`.

How do I get my `BytesAvailableFcn` (or some other function) to be called every time a carriage return is sent over an open serial connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Terminator character was not read because the input buffer was not large enough. Matlab defaults to an input buffer size of 512, and setting it to a larger value is simple:

```
s_connection.InputBufferSize = 4096;
```

Any value larger than the input being received will fix the issue.